# Should I create a new controller for my case?

Tags: cakephp, model-view-controller

Hey everyone I have a query. I have a products controller which has actions like add_product(), delete_product(), etc which perform CRUD operations on tbl_products table in database.

But I also have a requirement to also add product category like 2 for shoes, 3 for electronics, etc in a different table tbl_categories.

So should I create a different controller for categories or is it ok to include add_category action in products controller.

Please help.

Edit: But if I include add_category action in products controller then I cant write like this

```
echo $this->Form->create('Category',array("controller"=>"products","action"=>"add_category"));
```

because then I receive following error

```
 Error: CategoriesController could not be found.

 Error: Create the class CategoriesController below in file: app/Controller/CategoriesController.php

<?php
class CategoriesController extends AppController {

}
```

Comment: yes you should create a different table for categories as well as the controller and model, then create a relation between the two tables.

Comment: @Rik.esh Thank you Rik.esh but doesn't it go against the object oriented programming that all f(n)s that are related to each other and belong in same category products in my case should be grouped together in single class or multiple classes related to each other by inheritance.

Comment: there is no inheritance in this case because we are trying to create a relation between the two tables here not creating a single class for the two tables. I suggest  you to take a look at this associations tutorial https://the-nerd.be/2012/08/24/cakephp-basics-tutorial-part-4/ which will be helpful for you to understand the concept of association two tables.